# Finding records not updated in last k days efficiently

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a table which contains records of last **n** days. The records in this table are around 100 million. I need to find the records which are not updated in last k

My solution to this problem is

Partition the table on k1. Index on timestamp column. Now instead of updating the timestamp(so that index is not rebuilt), perform remove + insert. By doing this the I think the query to find the records not updated in last k days will be fast.

Is there any other better way to optimize these operations?

For example,

Suppose we have many users and each user can use different products. Also a user can start using(becomes owner) new products any time. If user does not use a product for n days his ownership expires. Now we need to find all the products for a user which are not used by him in last k days. The number of users are of order 10000 and number of products from which he can choose is of order 100,000.

I modeled this problem using a table with schema **(user_id, product_id, last_used)**. **product_id** is the id of the product the user is using. Whenever a user uses the product last_used is updated. Also a user's ownership of product expires if not used for n days by the user. I partitioned on the table on user_id and indexed last_used(timestamp). Also instead of updating I performed delete + create. I did partitioning and indexing for optimizing the query to **fetch records not updated in last k days for a user**.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: You've described the setup well, but please further describe the problem. You're deleting records older than x days and it's affecting read access? How many records are you deleting at a time? What's a typical delete query look like? InnoDB? There won't be any "rebuilding" of the index when deleting records, just some updates to it.

Comment: Please give an example of the results that you want from your query.

Comment: What's the primary key? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MarcusAdams Suppose we have a user table (user_id, product_id, last_used). product_id is the id of the product the user is using.  Whenever a user uses the product last_used is updated. Also a user can start using a new product any time. Now I need to find all the products for a user which are not used by him in last k days. Also a user's ownership of product expires if not used for n days by the user.
The index will be "re-build" if the index is on last_used and last_used is modified.

Comment: What else is in this table? Or is it just these three columns?

Comment: Just these three columns.

Answer (score 0):

You have said you need to "find" and, I think "expire" the records belonging to a particular user after a certain number of days.

Look, this can be done even in a large table with good indexing without too much trouble. I promise you, partitioning the table will be a l*ot of trouble*.  You have asserted that it's too expensive in your application to carry an index on your `last_used` column because of updates.  But, considering the initial and ongoing expense of maintaining a partitioned table, I strongly suggest you prove that assertion first. You may be wrong about the cost of maintaining indexes.

(Updating one row with a column that's indexed doesn't rebuild the index, it modifies it. The MySQL storage engine developers have optimized that use case, I promise you.)

As I am sure you know, this query will retrieve old records for a particular user.

```
SELECT product_id 
   FROM tbl
  WHERE user_id = <<<chosen user>>>
    AND last_used <= CURRENT_DATE() - <<<k>>> DAY
```

will yield your list of products.  This will work very efficiently indeed if you have a compound covering index on `(user_id, last_used, product_id)`. If you don't know what a compound covering index is, you really should find out using your favorite search engine. This one will random-access the particular user and then do a range scan on the last_used date. It will then return the product ids from the index.

If you want to get rid of all old records, I suggest you write a host program that repeats this query in a loop until you find that it has processed zero rows. Run this at an off-peak time in your application.  The `LIMIT` clause will prevent each individual query from taking too long and interfering with other uses of the table.  For the sake of speed on this query, you'll need an index on `last_used`.

```
DELETE FROM tbl
 WHERE last_used <= CURRENT_DATE() - <<<k>>> DAY
 LIMIT 500
```

I hope this helps. It comes from someone who's made the costly mistake of trying to partition something that didn't need partitioning.

Comment: Thank for replying. I will read about compound covering index. But if the last_used column is being updated very frequently, won't the index be modified with every update operation and make updates costly?

Comment: Deletes are buffered (fast), then the index is actually updated when the server is not busy, but you do still want to avoid long running transactions, so deleting a limited amount at a time isn't a bad idea if it's taking too long.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't "rebuild" indexes (not completely) when you modify an indexed value. In fact, it doesn't even reorder the records. It just moves the record to the proper 16KB page.

Within a page, the records are in the order they were added. If you inserted in order, then they're in order, otherwise, they're not.

So, when they say that MySQL's clustered indexes are in physical order, it's only true down to the page level, but not within the page.

Clustered indexes still get the benefit that the page data is on the same page as the index, so no further lookup is needed if the row data is small enough to fit in the pages. Reading is faster, but restructuring is slower because you have to move the data with the index. Secondary indexes are much faster to update, but to actually retrieve the data (with the exception of covering indexes), a further lookup must be made to retrieve the actual data via the primary key that the secondary index yields.

**Example**

Page 1 might hold user records for people whose last name start with A through B. Page 2 might hold names C through D, etc. If Bob renames himself Chuck, his record just gets copied over from page 1 to page 2. His record will always be put at the end of page 2. The keys are kept sorted, but not the data they point to.

If the page becomes full, MySQL will split the page. In this case, assuming even distribution between C and D, page 1 will be A through B, page 2 will be C, and page 3 will be D.

When a record is deleted, the space is compacted, and if the record becomes less than half full, MySQL will merge neighboring pages and possibly free up a page inbetween.

All of these changes are buffered, and MySQL does the actual writes when it's not busy.

The example works the same for both clustered (primary) and secondary indexes, but remember that with a clustered index, the keys point to the actual table data, whereas with a secondary index, the keys point to a value equal to the primary key.

**Summary**

After awhile, page splitting caused from random inserts will cause the pages to become noncontiguous on disk. The table will become "fragmented". Optimizing the table (rebuilding the table/index) fixes this.

There would be no benefit in deleting then reinserting the record. In fact, you'll just be adding transactional overhead. Let MySQL handle updating the index for you.

Now that you understand indexes a bit more, perhaps you can make a better decision of how to optimize your database.